# ExpandableListView - How can i print empty message if no childs present?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am developing an app which has an ExpandableListActivity. When a group has no children, I would like it to show a message that shows no children's are present.

Answer (score 0):

```
 expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            if(adapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition)==0) {
                //show message 
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: where should i write this?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: set nullpointer check in getChildrenCount of `adapter`, If null `return 0`